# Make notebook .txt or .json generated files within static folder persistent in bluemix

Tags: twitter, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I've been following the twitter tutorial for bluemix and watson and I've read that notebooks are short-lived but what about the .txt or .json files generated by running a notebook and saved under 'static' folder?

Whenever I re-run my application, those .txt and .json files are no longer there. Is there any way to make them persistent?

Thanks.

Comment: can you add a sample of your code here and provide more details? what tutorial are you following?

Comment: This is the tutorial I'm following: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/cc-ask-watson-part1-bluemix-trs/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the files to your git repository if you are using the IBM DevOps as described in the tutorial. Using this approach a brand new container for your application will be created every time you run `Build and Deploy` in your devops environment.

Or you can save a local copy to your root project directory and then it will be copied to your application container when you use `cf push` to deploy your application.

Cloud foundry applications are ephemeral so you should avoid writing to the local disk. As I mentioned in the first paragraph a brand new container is created every time your application is redeployed.

You can find more details [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html).